# Asp.net Core HealthChecks : AddDbContextCheck HealthReportEntry description and exception are empty when Unhealthy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, health-check

I use asp.net core HealthCheck in my application.

I use **microsoft.extensions.diagnostics.healthchecks.entityframeworkcore** package and AddDbContextCheck() extension method to add healthcheck on my DbContext.

When the state of this check is "Unhealthy" I've no feedback what is the error...

Other HealthChecks add error information in description and/or exception field of each HealthReportEntry of HealthReport

How can I have the detail error information of Unhealthy status for entityframeworkcore healthcheck ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As I know the `AddDbContextCheck` method by default does not include detailed error information, If you need more information implement you custom health check class like below:

```
public class DbContextHealthCheck<TContext>
    : IHealthCheck where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TContext _dbContext;

    public DbContextHealthCheck(TContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
        HealthCheckContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            // Perform a test query or operation on your DbContext
            // For example, you can execute a simple query like this:
            await _dbContext.Database.CanConnectAsync(cancellationToken);
            
            // DbContext is healthy
            return HealthCheckResult.Healthy();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If an exception is thrown, return an unhealthy result with the error details
            return HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("DbContext connection test failed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And then register health check in application startup

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>();
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<DbContextHealthCheck<YourDbContext>>("your_dbcontext_health_check");
```

If you would like to add more features you can use **[this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-7.0)** to read more about implementing custom health check